# Refreshing image on panel creates infinite loop (C# - Winforms)

Tags: c#, image, winforms, graphics, drawing

I'm having a problem with refreshing graphics on panels and forms.
When I draw the image it works fine but when I want to replace it with another image using Panel.Refresh it makes the event handler auto activate itself without end. If I use Panel.Update it will just draw the second image onto the first. A lot of people recommended that I use the Invalidate method but that has the same infinite loop problem.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Resources.Image1);

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     { 
          if (parameter == 0) { bitmap = new Bitmap(Resources.Image1); }
          if (parameter >= 2) { bitmap = new Bitmap(Resources.Image2); }
          e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 60, 10);
          panel1.Refresh();
     }
```

Comment: `panel1.Refresh();` or `Invalidate` trigger the `Paint` event again -> endless-loop. Remove it! Move it to where you change `parameter`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
panel1.Refresh();
```

Causes the paint event to trigger. I put the refresh code where the parameter value is changed.